# Convert Swift Data to String formatting using Dart

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I have a line of Swift code I need to convert to Dart for a Flutter project.

```
let str = data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

I am converting `Data` to a `String`. Or in Dart it would be a `ByteArray` to a `String` but with the proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `package:convert` package (note that this is *not* the same as `dart:convert`) then use:

```
var hex = hex.convert(bytes);
```

Comment: Yes, totally.  .